# PHP number minus same number not equal 0

Tags: php, numbers, calculator

I'm trying to minus 119.7 from 119.7 using PHP but the result is not expected (-1.4210854715202E-14), the expected result is 0

1. Doc1 RestToPay = 171
2. Doc2 RestToPay = 119.7

Here is my code:

```
$TotalAmountToPay = 290.7;
foreach($Docs as $Doc){
    $RestToPay = $Doc['RestToPay'];
    if($TotalAmountToPay <= 0){
        break;
    }
    $TotalAmountToPay = $TotalAmountToPay - $RestToPay;
    if($TotalAmountToPay >= 0){
        echo "OK: ".$TotalAmountToPay;
    }else{
        echo "Done: ".$TotalAmountToPay;
    }
}
```

Output I have got:

- OK: 119.7
- Done: -1.4210854715202E-14

Comment: You should also read [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Comment: The usually recommended way to avoid this issue is to work in pennies instead; 29070 rather than 290.70; the decimal point is only added just before showing the result to the user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should help.

```
$TotalAmountToPay = 290.7;
foreach($Docs as $Doc){
    $RestToPay = $Doc['RestToPay'];
    if($TotalAmountToPay <= 0){
        break;
    }
    $TotalAmountToPay = round($TotalAmountToPay,2) - round($RestToPay,2);
    if($TotalAmountToPay >= 0){
        echo "OK: ".$TotalAmountToPay;
    }else{
        echo "Done: ".$TotalAmountToPay;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like some type of way those numbers are being stored and converted are not equal.  You could always use the `round()` function which should get you what you want. So maybe try this:

```
$TotalAmountToPay = 290.7;
foreach($Docs as $Doc){
    $RestToPay = $Doc['RestToPay'];
    if($TotalAmountToPay <= 0){
        break;
    }
    $TotalAmountToPay = $TotalAmountToPay - $RestToPay;
    if($TotalAmountToPay >= 0){
        echo "OK: ".round($TotalAmountToPay,4);
    }else{
        echo "Done: ".round($TotalAmountToPay,4);
    }
}
```